# Compare without order and neglect comma in Excel VBA macro

Tags: excel, vba

I want to compare two columns with names, but they are in different format, for example, one is `Xu, Boxi`; the other is `BOXI XU`. So I need to compare it neglecting order and comma and not case sensitive.

So far I can solve the case sensitive part by using UPPER in Excel, but cannot solve the order and the comma problem. Here is my VBA code for the comparison function.

```
Sub Find_Matches()
    Dim CompareRange As Variant, x As Variant, y As Variant

    ' Set CompareRange equal to the range to which you will
    ' compare the selection.
    Set CompareRange = Range("C1:C5")
    ' NOTE: If the compare range is located on another workbook
    ' or worksheet, use the following syntax.
    ' Set CompareRange = Workbooks("Book2"). _
    '   Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C1:C5")
    '
    ' Loop through each cell in the selection and compare it to
    ' each cell in CompareRange.
    For Each x In Selection
        For Each y In CompareRange
            If x = y Then x.Offset(0, 1) = x
        Next y
    Next x   
End Sub
```

Another thing is that, as shown above, the loop is only from `C1 to C5`, how to let it loop until the end of the chart when I don`t know the index of the end?

Comment: End of chart? Where did the chart come from? I thought you wanted to compare columns?

Comment: To compare names with and without comma: if a name has a comma then use `Split(theName, ",")` to get an array of the two parts, then re-arrange the parts in reverse order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested:

```
Sub Find_Matches()
    Dim CompareRange As Variant, x As range, y As range
    dim sht as worksheet, n

    set sht = activesheet

    Set CompareRange = sht.Range(sht.range("C1"), _
                                 sht.cells(rows.count, 3).end(xlup))


    For Each x In Selection.cells
        n = normalize(x.value) 
        For Each y In CompareRange.cells
            If n = normalize(y.value) Then 
                x.Offset(0, 1) = x
                exit for
            end if
        Next y
    Next x   
End Sub

function normalize(v) as string
dim a
     v=trim(ucase(v))
     a=split(v,",")
     're-arrange if has single comma...
     if ubound(v)=1 then v= trim(a(1)) & " " & trim(a(0))
     normalize = v
end function
```